# Receiving "Access Denied" message when using Sharepoint API for GetUserProfilePropertyFor

Tags: user-profile-service, user-profile-property, office365apis

I am using SharePoint 2013 Online/Office 365.  Since I read that the _vin... user profile services through InfoPath are not available for the Office 365 version of SharePoint, I am trying a new approach through a workflow.

The workflow calls the API and is *suppose* to bring back the cell phone of the user based on the user account, however, each time I try it, I get the following error:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}

I should have full control however to the entire SharePoint site, so I'm wondering if something is wrong with my call to the API. In the workflow, I am calling the following HTTP Web service:

> https://SPSite.com/sites/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='CellPhone')?@v='DOMAIN\user'

and then recording the response from the result. No matter what I try, it is not working. Or is there a better way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to try different user with min contribute permission, also try to use workflow app permission...http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/p/178921/527970.aspx

Answer (score 1):

here is what MSFT stance on this:

> I should say that, REST service partly work in SharePoint Online. I’d
>   tried to confirm this question in our internal resource, and got the
>   information as the following:
>
> With the scenario we use REST service in InfoPath, it will works when
>   we preview forms in the client, as soon as we publish it to SharePoint
>   Online and trying to open it via a browser, it will throw errors.
>
> I hope this information helps.
>
> Thanks, Evan Zhang
>
> **Essentially**, this means that REST cannot be used with workflows or
>   InfoPath forms deployed/published to SharePoint online. Right?

**Yes, it's correct.**

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/178921.aspx?pi14715=2